# Initial Dropdown Menu Table Population

Tags: javascript, html, django, for-loop

I was wondering if someone could help me solve this problem I have. I created a form that populates a table based on the selected name in a dropdown menu, however, when I initially load the page, since it is a for-loop and no option has been selected yet, the for loop runs through all the datapoints, populating the table with all the data for each name, but works fine once an option is chosen. I was wondering if someone could explain how I can get the initial page load to either show nothing or the values of one option, not everything at once until an option is chosen. Thanks for the help.

```
   <form method="GET" action=".">
        <div id="option-wrap">

            <select name="option-menu" id="option-menu">
                    <option value="" hidden disabled selected value id="option-filler">Choose a Name</option>
                {% for l in options %}
                    <option value="{{loans.company_name}}">{{l.names}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>

        <button type="submit" class="btn-filter">Filter</button>
        </div>

        <div class="card-items">


            <table class="main-items-table">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items-identifiers">Name:</td>

                            {% for l in queryset %}
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items" href=""><span>{{l.name}}</span></td>
                            {% endfor %}

                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items-identifiers">Sector:</td>

                            {% for l in queryset %}
                            <td class="menu-box-tab-items" href="#6"><span>{{l.sector}}</span></td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>


                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Check to see if a value has been selected before you loop.  That way, you will loop only when a value is available.

Comment: Hi @AttemptedMastery , I'm a little confused by what you mean? If I'm understanding correctly, no value has been chosen yet so the form is populating the data associated with every single value in the option list. If you could clarify that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: To be frank, it sounds like it was working as intended.  Before a user picks an option, the dropdown displays all the potential options.  After a user picks one, the option should display within the input box.  Is this not how it's currently working?

Comment: @AttemptedMastery Yes everything in regards to the form selection/dropdown menu is working fine. Given that it is a form, if an option is not selected, no form is created, so before an option is selected, the table associated with the options populates the data of all options, essentially parsing out all the other options data once a selection is made. I am trying to figure out how to avoid the table filling in multiple columns of data because no option was selected. I think we may discussing two different questions. Hope this clarifies. Thanks.